# Is it possible to add custom fields to a WooCommerce attribute term?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-recommendation, advanced-taxonomy-queries

On `Wordpress / WooCommerce`, is it possible to add custom fields to a `WooCommerce` attribute term?

With "attributes" I mean the general attributes and not the attributes under products.

Please, check the image below for more details:

[image]

Is it possible to do it with `ACF` (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. And there's an easy guide [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/custom-location-rules/).

Below is a working code you can add to the theme's main *functions.php* file:

```
// Adds a custom rule type.
add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_types', function( $choices ){
    $choices[ __("Other",'acf') ]['wc_prod_attr'] = 'WC Product Attribute';
    return $choices;
} );

// Adds custom rule values.
add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_values/wc_prod_attr', function( $choices ){
    foreach ( wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() as $attr ) {
        $pa_name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attr->attribute_name );
        $choices[ $pa_name ] = $attr->attribute_label;
    }
    return $choices;
} );

// Matching the custom rule.
add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_match/wc_prod_attr', function( $match, $rule, $options ){
    if ( isset( $options['taxonomy'] ) ) {
        if ( '==' === $rule['operator'] ) {
            $match = $rule['value'] === $options['taxonomy'];
        } elseif ( '!=' === $rule['operator'] ) {
            $match = $rule['value'] !== $options['taxonomy'];
        }
    }
    return $match;
}, 10, 3 );
```

You'd get something like this on the ACF create/edit Field Group screen:

[image]

---

### UPDATED Sep 25 2018 (UTC)

In the function for matching the rule on the term edit page, the `$options['ef_taxonomy']` has been changed to `$options['taxonomy']` — back then, the array key `taxonomy` didn't exist (in my case), and it exists now, which I think replaces the `ef_taxonomy` key. Thanks [@JordanCarter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/94213/jordan-carter) for noticing the key issue, and [@VadimH](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/140129/vadim-h) for the initial answer's edit. =)

In that function, I also added the `if ( isset( $options['taxonomy'] ) )` check to avoid PHP's "undefined" notice. Thanks @JordanCarter for noticing this.

@VadimH, you can use `get_field( '{NAME}', 'term_{TERM ID}' )` to retrieve (and display) the field's value, like so:

```
$term_id = 123;
$value = get_field( 'my_field', 'term_' . $term_id );
```

See the "*Get a value from different objects*" section on the `get_field()`'s official [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).

*PS: The whole code (not just the `get_field()`) was last tried and tested on ACF 5.7.6 and ACF PRO 5.7.3, with WooCommerce 3.4.5.*

Comment: WC Product Attribute option is not there in the UI (ACF Pro v.5.7.3; WC v.3.4.3)

Comment: This works for me, except I had to change $options['ef_taxonomy'] to $options['taxonomy'] in the Matching custom rule filter

Comment: Thanks @JordanCarter. As I could recall it, that key wasn't available back then. So to everyone reading this, **use `$options['taxonomy']`** and *not* `$options['ef_taxonomy']`

Comment: @VadimH I've just tested the code on ACF 5.7.6 and ACF PRO 5.7.3, with WooCommerce 3.4.5, and the code still works well, except the `$options['ef_taxonomy']` which should be `$options['taxonomy']`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Actually, I ran into an error message on a single product page, saying that the "taxonomy" key doesn't exist. I wrapped the entire bit in an array_key_exists IF statement

Comment: @SallyCJ oops, sorry, forgot to paste the code into functions.php . And having corrected the $options, it all works now, thank you (I just edited this answer, it's getting peer-reviewed now).   Next question: how do you get that custom field's value in the site front-end?

Comment: @VadimH please check the updated answer. And thanks for noticing that Jordan.